# JQuery Mobile causes dates in Li to become links in iOS Safari

Tags: jquery, html, ios, jquery-mobile, safari

I'm having some trouble with implementing jquery mobile for my sortable list.

What's happening is that my sortable list works fine but its seems that jquery mobile is picking out the dates of the li elements and giving them an href which causes them to become links. This is only the case in iOS safari and it is fine on any other browser including Safari desktop

I've read that a similar thing happens with Jquery mobile and turning hrefs into "#"s but as far as I know this isn't the case since the li's do not have hrefs.

Thank you for your insights

Comment: iOS safari might be making them links to the iCal app. If this is the case, I'm not sure you can do much about it.

Comment: When I click on the links they say the links are invalid. The dates are formatted as 11/1/2011 and also appears to highlight other numbers that are behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to disable the automatic detection of Safari on iOS width the code below:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

This meta tag is for disableing automatic detection of phone number, but it may also work on your code.

The document is here:
"How do I disable automatic detection of phone numbers in webpages?"
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#codinghowtos/Mobile/UserExperience/_index.html

Thanks.